# Pyinstaller does not work together with silero tts

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller

I wanted to compile my code using the pyinstaller module, which uses siluro tts, but I encountered an error. To find out if I made a mistake in writing, I took a code example from the official github silero page (the code should create a file in which the bot pronounces the specified text):

```
import os
import torch

device = torch.device('cpu')
torch.set_num_threads(4)
local_file = 'model.pt'

if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
    torch.hub.download_url_to_file('https://models.silero.ai/models/tts/ru/v3_1_ru.pt',
                                   local_file)

model = torch.package.PackageImporter(local_file).load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
model.to(device)

example_text = 'В недрах тундры выдры в г+етрах т+ырят в вёдра ядра кедров.'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya'

audio_paths = model.save_wav(text=example_text,
                             speaker=speaker,
                             sample_rate=sample_rate)
```

The code works in PyCharm without problems, but when trying to open the compiled .exe file throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torch\hub.py", line 639, in download_url_to_file
    pbar.update(len(buffer))
  File "torch\hub.py", line 37, in update
    sys.stderr.write("\r{0:.1f}%".format(100 * self.n / float(self.total)))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "torch\hub.py", line 630, in download_url_to_file
    with tqdm(total=file_size, disable=not progress,
  File "torch\hub.py", line 50, in __exit__
    sys.stderr.write('\n')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Tell me, how can I fix this error?

I tried adding hidden import as it says [here](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/2470), but it didn't help and I realized that this problem occurs only when using silero tts models, and for example using te models for text editing, everything works fine.

Comment: welcome aki! Did you know about us?